# Get android notification from app?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I was thinking to build up an app to manage the notifications. I gave a look to the [Notification Manager](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html&rct=j&q=notification%20manager&ei=-qfvTdicBozIswb82KGvCg&usg=AFQjCNHUOCcxzecnfYhjV-g0mHeOHr2DXg&sig2=IjHdzSiximox-GOmpvaJ_w&cad=rja) but i didn't find anything that could help me. I'd like to get all the notifications (that are in the notification bar). Have you got any idea? Thanks, regards.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there's any possibility to do such thing using the public API. There are strict restrictions to what an app can access, for obvious security reasons. Each app is handled as a different user by the OS, so it has access only to public data and to the data owned by that app.

If you need this for a private project, you may consider modifying the android source code. I can't give you many details on how to do it, but I would start by looking at `com.android.server.NotificationManagerService` (source code [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=services/java/com/android/server/NotificationManagerService.java;h=73d17ea7d22d08a331e89786fd3b7ad5367573a4;hb=refs/heads/froyo)).

Comment: I thought to do that because i ported a sense rom, but leds don't work...so an app could have solved the problem.

Comment: Then the problem might be in the kernel or in services.jar. I can't tell about HTC phones, but take a look at xda's other ROMs with working leds for hints.